# Matplotlib step plot rotation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, step

I'm trying to rotate correctly the matplotlib step plot. First I swapped the x and y axes and reversed the y axis. I made the step plot again. However, the direction of the step line (blue color) was not as desired in the right picture and the red colored stepping line is the superimposed rotated image of the left picture. Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(14)
y = np.sin(x / 2)

fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(11.5, 5.5))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, bottom=0.13, top=0.98, right=0.97, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.0)

ax.step(x, y, where='mid', c='r')
ax.plot(x, y, 'o--', color='grey', alpha=0.3)

bx.invert_yaxis()
bx.step(y, x, where='pre', c='b')
bx.plot(y, x, 'o--', color='grey', alpha=0.3)

plt.show()
```

I am trying to make red colored step plot as shown in the right picture. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired step-style can be obtained by shifting a little bit the second coordinates and using `where=pre`.

```py
def plot_step_invert_mid(x, y, *args, **kwargs):
    y_new = np.insert(y, 0, y[0])
    y_new = 0.5 * (y_new[1:] + y_new[:-1])
    x_new = np.append(x, x[-1])
    y_new = np.append(y_new, y[-1])
    plt.step(x_new, y_new, where="pre", *args, **kwargs)

fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(11.5, 5.5))
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.08, bottom=0.13, top=0.98, right=0.97, wspace=0.2, hspace=0.0)

ax.step(x, y, where="mid", c='r')
ax.plot(x, y, 'o--', color='grey', alpha=0.3)

bx.invert_yaxis()
plot_step_invert_mid(y, x)
bx.plot(y, x, 'o--', color='grey', alpha=0.3)
```

[image: results]

Comment: Nice answer, I think it's good to leave the data unscathed.

Comment: A small drawback lies in the fact that `plot_step_invert_mid(y, x, "ro-")` will not display the  markers in the desired location.

Comment: Ah, right, I see what you mean... it's a tricky problem. Of course you can always plot the data itself. This would make a nice enhancement to matplotlib.

Comment: It is good answer without using external package. Thank you very much for defining a subroutine.

Comment: Thanks again @noin, What changes should be made for 'pre' and 'post' options of the step plot?

Comment: Basically switch both options! An inverted "pre" is a "post", and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to interpolate your original curve with [`scipy.interpolate.interp1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html) rather then use the `matplotlib.pyplot.step` method of plotting. This because `interp1d` generates a new vector that you can manipulate as you wish.
In the code below:

1. `x` and `y` are the original curve vectors (length 14)
2. `xx` and `yy` are the original curve interpolated vectors (length `N`)

In order to rotate the plot you can simply swap `x` with `y` and `xx` with `yy` in `plt.plot`:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.arange(14)
y = np.sin(x/2)

N = 1000
xx = np.linspace(0, 13, N)
yy = interp1d(x, y, kind = 'nearest')(xx)

fig, (ax, bx) = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, figsize = (11.5, 5.5))
fig.subplots_adjust(left = 0.08, bottom = 0.13, top = 0.98, right = 0.97, wspace = 0.2, hspace = 0.0)

ax.plot(xx, yy, 'r')
ax.plot(x, y, 'o--', color = 'grey', alpha = 0.3)

bx.invert_yaxis()
bx.plot(yy, xx, 'r')
bx.plot(y, x, 'o--', color = 'grey', alpha = 0.3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I find the original version of this answer more interesting because it generalized the problem to any angle.

Comment: Thank you, I think you are right, but in the original version the y axis wasn't reversed, so the answer didn't solve the specific issue of the questioner; I noticed it only later

Comment: This is quite an interesting solution,, but using a external subroutine is not desired, at least for me.